# Iptables script

Tags: server, iptables

What is the proper place to start/stop iptables script? Currently I have placed it into /etc/init.d and it has start/stop options. However I don't think it is the best place. The other two according to my research are

- `/etc/network/interface -> pre-up`
- `/etc/network/if-*.d` (will this one call my script with start/stop argument?)

So where is the proper place?

Comment: IMHO, `/etc/network/if-up.d/iptables` and `/etc/network/if-down.d/iptables` start to become confusing, I'd rather place it at `/etc/init.d` as you initially pointed out. Again, just my opinion.

Comment: Placing script into `init.d` will not restart iptables script when on interface restart(eg new IP address from DHCP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/etc/init.d is deprecated for this because there is then a race condition - for a few moments on restart, you have network up but do not have your firewall up.  **don't do it.**

typically what you want to do is get your firewall set up to your liking, then do `iptables-save > /etc/network/iptables`.  Now create `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables.sh` as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables
```

Be sure to remember to make both files owned by root, and `chmod 400 /etc/network/iptables ; chmod 755 /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables.sh` to set permissions appropriately - unprivileged users should not be able to read your actual firewall ruleset, much less change it, but your script in `if-pre-up.d` **must be executable.**  (You might optionally chmod it 700 if you're feeling frisky; but I don't see that it'll really keep anything any more secure.)

You do not need a *down* script for this, just a pre-up.  You *specifically* want pre-up because that keeps you from ever having your network interface online without your firewall up.